# Render html using filter

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-filter

I need to write a filter which renders html tags. 
This is my filter:

```
filters: {
  limitStrLength: function (value, maxLength) {
    if (value && value.length > maxLength) {
      let partialVal = value.substr(0, maxLength) + "...";
      return "<span title='" + value + "' >" + partialVal + "</span>";
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that I do not manage to render the raw html.

If I simply do:

```
<div>{{ productName  | limitStrLength(6) }}</div>
```

The html tags are rendered as string (i.e., I see on screen something like `<span title=...`).

I also tried using `v-html` attribute:

```
<div v-html="productName | limitStrLength(6)"></div>
```

But I get an error:

> Property or method "limitStrLength" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<div v-html="$options.filters.limitStrLength(productName, 6)"></div>
```

Source: [Github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4352)